# SQLAlchemy filter query with multiple table outerjoin

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have following three tables.

```
User:
[
   user_id
   first_name
   last_name
]

Picture:
[
   filename
   picture_type // eg: painting, photograph
   painter
]

Comment
[
   user_id
   filename
   comment
]
```

I am trying to query all filenames that was not reviewed by current user.

following line returns all the filenames that was reviewed and commented in the given picture_type

```
session.query(Picture.filename).outerjoin(Comment).filter(
                                       Picture.filename == Comment.filename,
                                       Picture.picture_type == 'photograph'
                                                        ).all()
```

, and the following line returns all the filenames in the in the given picture_type

```
session.query(Picture.filename).outerjoin(Comment).filter(
                                       Picture.picture_type == 'photograph'
                                                        ).all()
```

I was expecting following line would return filenames not reviewed in the in the given picture_type, but it returns an empty list

```
session.query(Picture.filename).outerjoin(Comment).filter(
                                       Picture.filename != Comment.filename,
                                       Picture.picture_type == 'photograph'
                                                        ).all()
```

Am I doing something wrong here?  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

i think your code have syntax error. are you missed a dot ? you wrote:

```
session.query(Picture.filename)outerjoin(Comment).filter(
                                   Picture.filename == Comment.filename,
                                   Picture.picture_type == 'photograph'
                                                    ).all()
```

but it should be like this:

```
session.query(Picture.filename).outerjoin(Comment).filter(
                                   Picture.filename == Comment.filename,
                                   Picture.picture_type == 'photograph'
                                                    ).all()
```

other sections also has this problem

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code with missing dot.  Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I researched Exclusive Join and figured out the problem.

It should have been **None == Comment.filename**, not **Picture.filename != Comment.filename**.

I fixed the code like below code and it is working now.

```
session.query(Picture.filename).outerjoin(Comment).filter(
                                   None == Comment.filename,
                                   Picture.picture_type == 'photograph'
                                                    ).all()
```

The problem was the resulting table of **left outer join** would not have any row that meet **left_field != right_field** condition.  The resulting rows would meet conditions **left_field == right_field** or **None == right_field** since the missing value in the right table would be marked as **null** in the resulting table.

Below link gave me good learnings about this subject.

http://www.datasavantconsulting.com/roland/sql_excl.html

Thanks all for trying to help.

However, I will still be open to better suggestions!!!